# Ternary operator using when

Tags: kotlin

How to write Kotlin conditional

```
if (a) b else c
```

using `when`

Comment: Please use Google next time. http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html

Comment: Perhaps you're too bothered with whether you could instead of whether you should. Pick the right tools for the job. If it's more appropriate to use if-else, such is in place of a ternary operator, then use it.

Comment: i just want readable version, when it's explicitly seen which will be chosen

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to use `var v = if (a) b else c` than using `when`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
when (a) {
  true -> b
  else -> c // or false -> c
}
```

as you see: `if`/`else` is easier to grasp in that particular case.

If `a` wouldn't just be a boolean, `when` may make more sense, e.g.:

```
when (a) {
  is Scalable -> TODO("scale it")
  else -> TODO("whatever makes sense")
}
```

New or other conditions can then easily be added... this however doesn't make much sense for simple boolean evaluations.

As you added a comment about readability and your sample shows just an assignment, maybe the following is more readable for you?

```
val c = if (x) "a"
        else "b"
```

or if you want to simulate something similar as a ternary operator:

```
val c = x.takeIf { it }?.let { "a" }
        ?: "b"
```

I hope however that you get the point... if you just have a `boolean` use `if`/`else`. But if your condition is more complex, also something like `takeIf` might be helpful... (I am really sorry that I used `x.takeIf { it }` here... but it should rather be a demonstration of what is possible).

Comment: nice one! used this: var c = when (x) { true -> "a" false -> "b" }

Comment: @andreikashin I really think that there's no point in avoiding `if` here...